# Adding 64 bits slice to iOS application yields crash

Tags: c++, ios, memory, boost, 64-bit

I'm currently porting an application that only supported 32 bits archs until now to support 64 bits archs as well, as requested by Apple since February, 1st.

Now, just by adding `arm64` to the valid architectures, I get a strange double free error on `boost::format` related code. I get the following error message:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1703eaa00: Freeing already free'd pointer
```

which happens in the following code:

```
std::string ExceptionHelper::generateDebugTrace(const std::exception& exception, 
                                                size_t indent) {
    boost::format innerMessage("Thrown: %3%\n%1%Type: %2%\n");
    innerMessage % std::string(indent + ExceptionHelper::log_indent_size, ' ');
    innerMessage % boost::units::detail::demangle(typeid(exception).name());
    innerMessage % exception.what();
    return innerMessage.str();
}//Happens when exiting scope
```

on the last line, i.e. when exiting the function's scope, and seems related to a `boost::io::basic_altstringbuf` deallocation.

I tried getting info from the object being doubly free'd (using lldb `print` command) but as it breaks after at least a free, I don't get anything meaningful by using this command.

As `Enable Malloc Guard` isn't available when running the application on a device (and I can't run it in the simulator), I don't really know how I can debug this error and know precisely what causes the double delete.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/

Comment: sounds like a memory smasher. Have you tried using Instruments?

Comment: @SamMiller Yep, but without success for now. I believe it's not tracable using NSZombies as it's not Objective-C code. What bugs me is that it seems to be completely on boost part. And I have it compiled with 64 bits support.

Answer (score 0):

Problem comes from the method
`virtual const char* what() const throw()`
which was overridden and returned a c_str() of a local string variable.

The strange thing is that this code worked in 32 bits by luck for 2 years, but crashed on 64 bits at each run.